# linq order by from second table count

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I have lets say two tables:
Student(id, name);
Class (id, name, student_id);

how I can select all students, but ordered by classes count?

```
Students:
1, "John"
2, "Andrew"

Classes:
1, french, 1
2, french, 2
3, Spanish, 1
4, English, 1
```

It should order:

```
John
Andrew
```

Right now I get students:

```
return entites.students.Include(w=>w.classes).ToList();
```

Order part is missing...

**EDIT**
Great, it works, but how it should looks, when classes table is in schools table and I want to get students ordered by schools count?

```
Students (id, name);
Classes (id, name, students_id);
Schools (id, name, classes_id);

Students:
1, "John"
2, "Andrew"

Classes:
1, french, 1
2, french, 2
3, Spanish, 1
4, English, 1
5, English, 2

Schools:
1, "Primary school", 1
2, "Secondary school", 2
3, "Another school", 5
```

It should give me:

```
Andrew
John
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your file has a

```
using System.Linq;
```

above the namespace directive, you can do:

```
entities.students.Include(s => s.classes).OrderBy(s => s.classes.Count());
```